# Filtered the Odata service value for date range with and:false condition SAPUI5

Tags: javascript, filter, odata, sapui5

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8Nv9.png)
i would like to implement sap.ui.model.Filter which have new sap.ui.model.Filter(sPath, sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.BT, vValue1, vValue2);
like this i have 8 field i am filtering like this only 
 but for 2 field i need to implement the **and:False** condition.

https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.Filter

```js
   var product = comboBoxValue.products;
   product.forEach(function (allproduct) {
    allproduct = allproduct.toUpperCase();
     var productValue1 = new sap.ui.model.Filter("PRODUCT", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains, allproduct);
     
    filters.push(productValue1);
   });
 
// filter the Country values 
   var country = comboBoxValue.locations;
   country.forEach(function (allcountry) {
    // allcountry = allcountry.toUpperCase();
     var countryValue = new sap.ui.model.Filter("COUNTRY", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains, allcountry);
    
     
    // filters.push(countryValue);
   });
 
   // filter the Status value 
   var status = comboBoxValue.status1;
   status.forEach(function (allstatus) {
    // allcountry = allcountry.toUpperCase();
     var statusValue = new sap.ui.model.Filter("SUB_STATUS1", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains, allstatus);
   
    filters.push(statusValue);
   });

   // filter the Change type values
   var change_type = comboBoxValue.changes;
   change_type.forEach(function (allchanges) {
    // allcountry = allcountry.toUpperCase();
     var changeValue = new sap.ui.model.Filter("CHANGE_TYPE", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains, allchanges);
   
     
    filters.push(changeValue);
   });

   // filter the Submission type values
   var sub_type = comboBoxValue.Submissions1;
   sub_type.forEach(function (allsub) {
    allsub = allsub.toUpperCase();
     subValue = new sap.ui.model.Filter("SUB_TYPE", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains, allsub);
      
    filters.push(subValue);
   });

   // filter the Manufacturing Stage
   var manu_stage = comboBoxValue.stages1;
   manu_stage.forEach(function (allstage) {
    allstage = allstage.toUpperCase();
     var stageValue = new sap.ui.model.Filter("MANUFACTURING_STAGE", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains, allstage);
    
    filters.push(stageValue);
   });
```

**filters** is array i am passing to oData service like

```js
 oModel6.read("/gantt", {
    filters: filters,
    success: function (oData, oResponse) {
     // checking if its region Gantt Chart view
     console.log("filtered data will come in oData ");
          }
          error: function(e){
          
          }
          });
```

now i have give six 
filters.push(productValue1);    passing the after 
var productValue1 = new sap.ui.model.Filter("PRODUCT", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains, allproduct);
                 filtering it using the Sapui5 control filter.
to array filters.
Now i want 2 more filter for date range as

```js
for (var g = 0; g < comboBoxValue.date_type.length; g++) {
    
    var range = new sap.ui.model.Filter(comboBoxValue.date_type[g], sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.BT, sFrom, sTo);
  oFilter.push(range);
   
   }
```

in this i am passing the multiple comboBoxValue.date_type values and start date, end date for it
For other filter its standard sapui5 taking **and:true** (you refer https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.Filter this link)

but for this particular filter i need to give and:false 
and give this and:false to my filter array called **filters**

final statement : total 8 value  where 6 are normal stadard filter with **and:true** and storing in  **filters** array and 2 more field  date range with dat_type want **and:false**
and store this in  **filters** array

In Image 2 values are i want in **and:false** and other in **and:true**

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your issue, you have a total of 8 condition for which you want 6 of them to be concatenated with an "or" and two of them with an "and". This behaviour is explained in the [docs](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.Filter%23constructor) with sample #3.

```
new Filter({
filters: [
  ...
  new Filter({
    path: 'Quantity',
    operator: FilterOperator.LT,
    value1: 20
  }),
  new Filter({
    path: 'Price',
    operator: FilterOperator.GT,
    value1: 14.0
  })
  ...
],
and: true|false
```

})

This shows you that you can nest filters in filters, which would be the way for you to solve your issue. In your case you would need three layers of nesting.